# Magento 2.3 Ajax Breadcrumb Product-Detail

Tags: ajax, magento2.3, breadcrumbs

When the Product-Detail Page is loaded, on Magento 2.3 the Breadcrumb is loaded via an Ajax request. This causes a large delay, because of the amount of requests on the product page.

How could I disable this Ajax request and change the load of the breadcrumb within the product detail request?

Comment: Any news on this? I am experiencing the same.

Comment: Sadly i have to say: no :/

Comment: I have reduced that time by setting `Enable Search Recommendations` and `Enable Search Suggestions` to `No` under `Catalog Search`    configuration and by using `Varnish` cache.